# How can i sum up timestamps with pandas.groupby()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

i have a log(detection.csv) of detected class in a script

```
HP,0:00:08 
Kellogs,0:02:03 
Rayban,0:00:25 
Skechers,0:00:09 
Rayban,0:04:26 
Skechers,0:02:34 
HP,0:00:57 
Rayban,0:00:14 
HP,0:00:02 
HP,0:00:08 
Kellogs,0:02:06 
Rayban,0:00:26 
Skechers,0:00:10
```

The question is is there an way to sum up the time-duration of detected class with using pandas.groupby() method or any other method

Note: both columns are in format of strings

when i am using pandas.groupby()method the result is not summing up

[image]

`OverallCode:`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


csvdata=[]
with open('result2.txt','r+') as myfile:
 for lines in myfile:
  line=myfile.read()
  line=line.replace('  ',',')
  csvdata.append(line)

#print(csvdata)

with open('detection.csv','w') as newfile:
 for i in range(len(csvdata)):
  line=csvdata[i]
  newfile.write(line)
  newfile.close()

df=pd.read_csv('detection.csv',names=['class', 'timestamp'],header=None)

#ndf=df.groupby(['class'])['timestamp'].sum()
#print(ndf)


df['timestamp'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['timestamp'])

def format_timedelta(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 
        
df1 = df.groupby('class')['timestamp'].sum().apply(format_timedelta).reset_index()
print (df1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with convert column to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

df1 = df.groupby('company', as_index=False)['time'].sum()
print (df1)
    company            time
0        HP 0 days 00:01:15
1   Kellogs 0 days 00:04:09
2    Rayban 0 days 00:05:31
3  Skechers 0 days 00:02:53
```

For original format use custom function:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

def format_timedelta(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 
        
df1 = df.groupby('company')['time'].sum().apply(format_timedelta).reset_index()
print (df1)
    company     time
0        HP  0:01:15
1   Kellogs  0:04:09
2    Rayban  0:05:31
3  Skechers  0:02:53
```

EDIT: You can simplify your code:

```
csvdata=[]
with open('result2.txt','r+') as myfile:
 for lines in myfile:
  line=myfile.read()
  line=line.replace('  ',',')
  csvdata.append(line)

#print(csvdata)

with open('detection.csv','w') as newfile:
 for i in range(len(csvdata)):
  line=csvdata[i]
  newfile.write(line)
  newfile.close()

df=pd.read_csv('result2.csv',names=['class', 'timestamp'],header=None)
```

to:

```
#convert txt with tab separator
df=pd.read_csv('result2.txt',names=['class', 'timestamp'],header=None, sep='\t')
```

Comment: the result is not summing up in mine one

Comment: @NotSoFamous - no error, no summing? I tis weird, for me working really well.

Comment: @NotSoFamous - There is problem tab separator, do you try `df = pd.read_csv('detection.csv', sep='\t')` instead `df = pd.read_csv('detection.csv')` ?

Comment: @ezrael i have updated the question using above code still same result can you show me where i am lacking

Comment: @NotSoFamous - in original csv is coma or tab separator?

Comment: @basically it was `.txt` file with `\t` as a seprator from `class/company` using above code i first converted into `.csv` by replacing `\t` with `,`

Comment: @NotSoFamous - hmmm, answer is edited. I think there is converting to `,` csv not necessary.

Comment: @ezrael can you show again conversion of dataframe to `.txt`

Comment: @NotSoFamous - Last use `df1.to_csv('file.txt', index=False)` ;) it is not problem in `to_csv` write to `txt`

Comment: @jezarel Thnx You saved me lot of tym :)